# How do I install Mysql 5.0.75 instead of Mysql 5.5

Tags: ubuntu, mysql

I have a new Ubuntu Micro instance on Amazon EC2. The default ami-8cfa58e5.

I have made a backup of an older MySQL database by snapshotting the volume the data is stored on. I now need to recover from that backup. When I install mysql using: sudo apt-get install mysql-server I get the latest version 5.5. When I then go through and mount the drives per this document: http://aws.amazon.com/articles/1663?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

Everything works ok, but MySQL will not start. I think this may be because the backed up instance is using mysql 5.0.75. I'm not an expert on Linux, how can I install Mysql 5.0.75 to test if that is the cause of my problem?

Comment: What do your logs say - check /var/log/mysql/error.log and add any relevant information to your question.

Comment: There doesn't appear to be an error.log. I see mysql.err and mysql.log but both are empty.

Comment: I was able to get mysql 5.5 to open the 5.0.75 database file by removing the default character set from my.cnf

Answer (score 1):

You can install a previous version of a package in Ubuntu using `apt-get` as follows

```
sudo apt-get install foo_package=version
```

but for for ami-8cfa58e5 (Ubuntu 12.04 Precise) the version you want to test was never packaged, the oldest release from `mysql-server` for 12.04 is mysql-server 5.1.58-1ubuntu1 and can be installed with

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server=5.1.58
```

To get 5.0.75 you would need to use and older Amazon EC2 image.

Answer (score 0):

If you feel a little adventurous, I have a link to the Source Code of MySQL 5.0.75

Courtesy of SkySQL : http://downloads.skysql.com/archive/index/p/mysql/v/5.0.75

Download the Source Code to Amazon EC2 and run `make` installation

Please let us know if this helped

Answer (score 0):

It seems an permission issue , please make sure you have correct permission and correct owner setup for your Mysql Data directory.

```
  chown mysql:mysql /PathtoMysqldatadirectory
```